# Load an Ember.JS template once it has been requested by the user (i.e. a link serving that template has been clicked)?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, ember.js, handlebars.js

I've got this:

```
{{#link-to "register"}}Register{{/link-to}}
```

The problem is, I don't want to load `register.hbs` - the file in which I keep the register handlebar straightaway, but want to load it right after the user clicks on the link, and delay the template from loading until the handlebar has loaded.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't understand this part: "delay the template from loading until the handlebar has loaded."  What is your use case that you want some sort of delay?

Comment: @SteveH. Sorry - it means it isn't loaded until the user clicks the link, which is when it starts loading.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you mostly can, but it'll probably provide a slower user experience than just loading them up front, or precompiling and loading them up front.

So in your particular use case you'd stop the transition from occurring, fetch and compile the template, then retry the transition.

The general idea looking like this

```
App.ColorRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function(transition){
    if(!Em.TEMPLATES.color){
      transition.abort();
        $.ajax({
          url: '/templates/color.hbs',
          success: function(data) {
            Em.TEMPLATES.color = Em.Handlebars.compile(data);
            transition.retry();
          }
       });
    }

  },
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('color', params.id);
  }
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/866/edit

And you could make it a bit more reusable by creating a mixin and applying it to routes that you want to implement this pattern on.

```
App.TemplateMixin = Em.Mixin.create({
  templateRequired: null,
  beforeModel: function(transition){
    var template = this.get('templateRequired');
    if(template && ! Em.TEMPLATES[template]){
       transition.abort();
       $.ajax({
          url: '/templates/'+ template + '.hbs',
          success: function(data) {
            Em.TEMPLATES[template] = Em.Handlebars.compile(data);
            transition.retry();
          }
       });

    }
  }
});

App.ColorRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.TemplateMixin,{
  templateRequired:'color',
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('color', params.id);
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/867/edit

#### One last statement

Now that I think about it, you don't need to abort and retry the transition, the before model takes a promise and you can just return a promise which would allow any loading route to stay active.

```
App.TemplateMixin = Em.Mixin.create({
  templateRequired: null,
  beforeModel: function(transition){
    var template = this.get('templateRequired');
    if(template && ! Em.TEMPLATES[template]){

       return $.ajax({
          url: '/templates/'+ template + '.hbs'
       }).then(function(data){
          Em.TEMPLATES[template] = Em.Handlebars.compile(data);
       });
    }
  }
});

App.ColorRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.TemplateMixin,{
  templateRequired:'color',
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('color', params.id);
  }
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/868/edit

#### I lied, last note

Following any of the last two patterns you need to be aware of the fact that the mixin is overriding the default implementation of `beforeModel`.  So if you want to apply it on the route as well you'd need to call `this._super(transition)` from the route to call the  mixin implementation.

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/869/edit

Comment: Great answer. Can you see a scenario in which you would want to do this? Just seems so smelly. If your app loads with variable template code, that just seems like a step back into spaghetti land.

Comment: Not really, like I said, it's a slower user experience.  Maybe if you were hiding templates by not serving them, or maybe you needed to be authenticated before serving templates, I dunno, it seems like overkill to me.  A ton of extra code for a lesser experience.  Maybe they have 10,000 templates and a ridiculous router.